# A different method of finding the potential function $f(x, y)$ of a vector field $\textbf{F}(x, y).$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

If $\textbf{F}(x, y) = \langle 3 + 2xy, x^2 - 3y^2 \rangle,$ find a function $f$ such that $\textbf{F} = \nabla f.$

I know how to solve this problem, but my question is whether the following technique would work in general, because it's slightly different than the technique presented in the book.

Whatever $f$ is, we know that $f_x = 3 + 2xy$ and $f_y = x^2 - 3y^2,$ so $f(x, y) = \int(3+2xy)\;dx = 3x+x^2y+g(y)$ and $f(x, y) = \int(x^2 - 3y^2)\;dy = x^2y - y^3 + h(x).$

From here, we know that $f(x, y) = 3x+x^2y+g(y) = x^2y - y^3 + h(x),$ so $g(y) = -y^3 + K$ and $h(x) = 3x + K.$ So the final answer is $f(x, y) = x^2y+3x-y^3+K.$ I know this is the correct answer, but the part I'm questioning is the jump to assuming what $g(y)$ and $h(x)$ are. Does this always work? I've yet to find an example where it doesn't work.

The technique the book uses is to use $f(x, y) = 3x+x^2y+g(y)$ to get $f_y = x^2+g'(y),$ and since we know that $f_y = x^2 - 3y^2,$ then $g'(y) = -3y^2.$ From here, $g(y) = \int g'(y) \;dy = \int -3y^2\; dy = -y^3 + K.$ So the final answer is still $f(x, y) = x^2y+3x-y^3+K.$

Even though I know I how to get the answer, I'm wondering if the first technique works because I don't see it taught in my textbook, or anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

They are essentially only slight variations of the same technique.

You determined that $f(x,y)= 3x+x^2y+g(y) = h(x)+x^2y-y^3$ by integrating the two give derivatives (wrt to the relevant variables), then figured out what the function $g(y)$ must be by comparison.

They determined that $f_y(x,y) = x^2+g'(y)$ by integrating (wrt $x$) and derivating (wrt $y$) one of the given derivatives $f_x(x,y)$, then figured out what the derived function must be by comparison with the given derivative $f_y(x,y)$; and integrating that gives $g(y)$.

$${~~~~g(y)=K-y^3\\~\\f(x,y)=3x+x^2y-y^3+K}$$